# MIPS indentation when global variable names are longer than one tab worth of space

Tags: assembly, coding-style, mips, indentation

As far as I know, when writing in MIPS, you should write the global variable name, add a colon, then tab to finish the tab, then write the details of the variable, for example, with an 8 character tab, you get something like:

```
        .data
abc:    .asciiz "ashdjkashd"
abcd:   .asciiz "uwbdjkwbd"
abcde:  .asciiz "qwjkeqhwe"
```

Now I'm not sure if I'm just not googling well enough but I can barely find any resources / videos around basic MIPS.
The question have is if the variable name is longer than one tab space, how should I fix the indentation?

```
        .data
abc:    .asciiz "wdhwjbdjhw"
abcdefghi:      .asciiz "bashjdkhasd"
```

This was the first alternative I thought of (finishing the next possible tab), but it honestly doesn't look clean so I'm assuming there's a way to go about indenting in this situation.

```
        .data
abc:            .asciiz "wdhwjbdjhw"
abcdefghi:      .asciiz "bashjdkhasd"
```

I also considered this, but I'm not sure it's what is considered "conventional".

Comment: assembly language is specific to the tool not the target (mips), what tool are you using to read this code?

Comment: some assembly languages want labels or directives to start on the first column but for whitespace in between, usually they dont care, tabs or spaces and how much.  There are exceptions of course.  understand, again, assembly languages vary, for the same target, among the different tools for that target, there is never an expectation that mips asm code works on all mips assemblers.  arm on arm assemblers, x86, etc...

Comment: I'm using mars ide? I'm not sure if that's what you're asking @old_timer

Comment: yes, that is what I was asking.  For future reference this should be part of any assembly language question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no convention universally agreed upon, the same way that people don't universally agree on indentation of higher level languages, what with the `{` on the end of the line or on their own line.

Further, there's another alternative to your two choices, and I prefer this b/c it means you don't have to go back an reformat shorter lines when you find the need for a longer line:

```
        .data
abc:    .asciiz "ashdjkashd"
abcd:   .asciiz "uwbdjkwbd"
abcde:  .asciiz "qwjkeqhwe"
abcdefghi:
        .asciiz "bashjdkhasd"
```

This may seem awkward as many learning assembly think of labels as labeling some section of code or data that is between the label and the next label.  But labels are technically just a name to be associated with one single point (address) in the program, not necessarily labeling the upcoming sequence of code or data.  In that context, labels being alone on their own line makes a lot of sense.

A structured statement, shown here:

```
if ( <if-condition> ) { <then-part> } else { <else-part> }
```

Translated into the if-goto-label style of assembly (but still shown in C):

```
    if ( ! <if-condition> ) goto if1ElsePart;
    <then-part>
    goto if1Done;
if1ElsePart:
    <else-part>
if1Done:
```

When the if-statement is completed, execution continues with the next statement after the if, whether or not the then part executed or the else part executed.  The label `if1Done` is the point where the control flow split by the if statement rejoins together to run whatever statement comes after the if.

So, this translation by pattern requires labels to identify the points in the code for the branch targets, rather than necessarily labeling what the upcoming code actually does (i.e. what the else part and statement after the if actually does).

Putting labels alone on a line makes editing of surrounding code or data easier in some sense, and, the translation approach by pattern matching makes naming of labels relate to the structure of the control statements rather than behavior of sections.

Comment: Thank you so much, if there isn't a defined convention, is the double indentation that I did considered okay?

Comment: There nothing wrong with double indentation.  You can write your code as you see fit.  Generally speaking, indentation style will be imposed (or not) by the group or company that you work with, so that's where contention is found.

Comment: I see, this is just for uni and they haven't said anything related to this, so I guess it's safe to assume anything goes. Well, once again, thank you very much!